# Dice game, get close to $6$

Tags: probability, game-theory

> You have been chosen to play a game involving a 6-sided die. You get
>   to roll the die once, see the result, and then may choose to either
>   stop or roll again. Your payoff is the sum of your rolls, unless this
>   sum is (strictly) greater than 6. If you go over $6$, you get $0$. What's the best strategy?

I tried to set up equations with expected value. I think that the best strategy is to roll until you get at least some value, call it $x$. But I have not been able to make too much progress. Can someone please help me?

Comment: So...study that strategy.  Easy to compute if your threshold, $x$, is $1$.  (as that just means you roll once and stop).  What if $x=2$?  $3$?

Comment: @lulu If $x = 2$, you roll again only if you get a $1$. So I guess the expected gain is $\frac{5}{6}(4) + \frac{1}{6}(1 + 3.5) = 4.08333333$, is that right? And if $x = 3$, then we reroll if  we get a $1$ or $2$, so we get $\frac{4}{6}(4.5) + \frac{2}{6}(5) = 4.66666667$... Are these calculations okay? If $x = 3$ then we reroll if we get a $1, 2, 3$, which means our expected gain is $\frac{1}{3}(2 + 3.5) + \frac{1}{3}(5) = 3.5$. It starts to level off here, so I think the best is $x=3$

Comment: Are you allowed to roll more than twice if you wish?

Comment: Yes you can roll as many times as you want.

Comment: I get $3.888...$ for $x=2$, but I did it quickly.

Comment: I got $4.083333$ but I am not confident in how I'm calculating them. Is my work okay?

Comment: To get $3.8888$:   with $x=1$ either you roll $>1$ initially and stop or you roll a $1$ initially and then roll again and stop, whatever you get.  Thus $E_1=\frac {2+3+4+5+6}6+\frac 16\times {2+3+4+5+6}6=3.88888$

Comment: I think that does not add up to $3.8888$

Comment: It does I just formatted it incorrectly.  Should read $E_1=\frac {2+3+4+5+6}6+\frac 16 \times \frac {2+3+4+5+6}6=3.\overline 3 +.\overline 5 = .\overline 8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $x$, you fail and get $0$ with probability $\frac x6$, losing $x$.  If you succeed, you gain a number between $1$ and $6-x$, so on average gain $$\frac {6-x}6\cdot \frac 12(7-x)-\frac x6\cdot x$$ 
Just make a table of this and see where it goes negative.  It turns out the gain is $\frac 73$ at $x=1$, $1$ at $x=2$ and negative above that, so you should roll again when you have $2$ or less.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I do not think this is right. I think you meant something else

Comment: @lulu:  the first denominator should have been $6$.  Fixed.  It now says to roll again  on $1$ or $2$

Comment: @lulu:  I was calculating the gain of one roll assuming you have $x$.  The fact that this is positive at $x=1$ means you should roll again.  At $x=2$ it gives $1$, so you should roll again at $2$ as well

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x,t)$ is your expected return if so far you have rolled $x$ and you have a threshold $t$ where you stop when $x \ge t$.  Then

- $f(x,t)=0$ if $x\gt 6$ as you are bust
- $f(x,t)=x$ if $t \le x \le 6$ as you stop
- $f(x,t)=\frac16 \sum\limits_{y=x+1}^{x+6} f(y,t)$ if $0 \le x \lt t$ as you reroll

You are interested in $f(0,t)$ for different $t$, and you get

```
t   f(0,t)
1   3.5
2   3.888888889
3   4.083333333
4   3.969907407
5   3.396476337
6   2.161394033
```

So the optimal position is with $t=3$, rerolling if you have a total of $1$ or $2$ and otherwise stopping.  This makes the game worth $4.083333333$ as you found